# how to find the max 'n' values for data based on SUM of values?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Below is the table

> Amt |  Val    | Location
>   230 |   a |   DEL
>   450 |   b  |  KOL
>   670 |   c  |  BLR
>   890 |   d  |  DEL
>   111 |   e  |  KOL
>   133 |   a  |  KOL
>   155 |   b  |  DEL
>   177 |   c  |  BLR
>   199 |   a  |  DEL
>   221 |   b  | BLR
>   243 |   c  |  BLR
>   265 |   d  |  KOL
>   287 |   a  |  KOL
>   309 |   b  |  DEL
>   331 |   c  |  DEL
>   353 |   d  |  KOL
>   375 |   e  |  BLR
>   397 |   a  |  BLR
>   419 |   b  |  DEL
>   441 |   c  |  KOL

out of a,b,c,d,e values how to find the maximum 2 values for respective location based on the a's..b's..c's..d's..e's  amount.
I am able to get the sum of values of top 2 **val** through Pivot table, for one location
**Please tell how to get the top `2` val with their sum of amount for all location simultaneously through VBA**,

I have Posted VBA code for the same, which gives result for only one location.

Sorry not able to upload the snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   1. Insert a Pivot Table.
   2. Add Val in Row Labels.
   3.  Add Location in column Labels.
   4.  Add Amt in Values field(Sumof Amt).

    Now In created Pivot Table,  

   1.  In column labels filter for only one location(eg: Blr).
   2.  In Row Labels filter apply value filters and select Top 10..(last item).
   3.  In place of 10(by default) give 2.

   4.  Now the table consists of Top 2 val with their sum of Amount for BLR Location.
```

VBA Code for the Same:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook

    With wkbk.Sheets(1)
    LastRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    LastCol = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    Set rngSource = .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    End With

       With wkbk.Sheets(2)
       Set dst = .Range("a1")
       End With  With wkbk
    Sheets(1).PivotTableWizard _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=rngSource, _
    TableDestination:=dst, _
    TableName:="Pivotinfo"
    End With

    With wkbk.Sheets(2).PivotTables("Pivotinfo")
        .PivotFields("Val").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Location").Orientation = xlColumnField



            With .PivotFields("Amt")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlSum  With wkbk.Sheets(2).PivotTables("Pivotinfo").PivotFields("Location")
    .PivotItems("DEL").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("KOL").Visible = False
    End With

    With wkbk.sheets(2).PivotTables("Pivotinfo").PivotFields("Val").AutoShow _
    xlAutomatic, xlTop, 2, "Sum of Amt"
    End With
    End With
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Say your data is in A1 thru C20.  You have three unique locations: DEL, KOL, BLR.

In D1 enter:

**=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A$20)*(C$1:C$20=C1))**  and copy down thru D3

In E1 enter:

**=LARGE(D1:D3,1)**

In E2 enter:

**=LARGE(D1:D3,2)**

Should look like:

[image]

EDIT:

based upon your comment, the highest two values for DEL would be:

**=LARGE(IF(C1:C20="del",A1:A20),1)**

and

**=LARGE(IF(C1:C20="del",A1:A20),2)**

These are array formulas that must be entered with **CNTRL-SHFT-ENTER** rather than just the **ENTER** key

Comment: Hi, solution should be like eg:TOP two val of DEL i.e., b and d with their corresponding values for DEL location.

Answer (score 0):

**DMAX** function returns the largest number in a column in a list or database, based on a given criteria.

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dmax.php